# how to access variable inside OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, click, listener

I have a double that I created inside one on click listener and I want to access it in a separate on click listener in the same java file. every time I type the variable name it comes up in red, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, declare it as a global variable of your class.

```
class MainActivity
{
    String editableString;

    public void onCreate() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course!

```
class X { 
    String s;
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            s = field1.getText();
            field2.setText(s);
        }
    });
}
```

In this example, I did exactly what you asked for :). Just declare the variable OUTSIDE the Listener, then you'll be able to access it wherever you want. CAUTION: Beware the "NullPointerExceptions". If you declare something without initializing it, like I did "String s;", its default value is null. If you try to access it before initializing it, you will receive null.

Comment: thanks, eventually I realized it needed to be at the very top of my class and it all worked

Comment: Once more, be careful with the nullpointerexceptions. This error is really really common when you declare something "at the very top of the class" :).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a custom listener class that implements the OnClickListener class and pass object of the class into the setOnClickListener method. You can set the global variables local inside the custom class using its constructor. Then you can access the local variables inside the listener methods. I hope that it will solve your problem.

```
abstract class CustomOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
int id;
String name;

    public abstract boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event);

    CustomOnClickListener(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You may find this useful, [Create a custom event listener in Android](https://jkcodeblog.blogspot.com/2020/10/create-custom-event-listener-in-java.html)